# Why aren't all of my map output records being reduced?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MapReduce job with the following counters

```
Map output records:   1,256,043,797
Reduce input records: 1,027,012,342
```

I'm not using a combiner, so I'm surprised that there are fewer records in the reduce than were produced by the map.  What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you give more details of your code related to mapper and reducer may be that could clear out.

Comment: Are additional map jobs being run due to speculative execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this was happening because my reduce wasn't iterating through all of the values for some keys.  The counter shows the number of reduce records consumed, so it would only equal the map output records if the reducer went all the way through the iterator for every key.